# Ошибка: java: not a statement

Tags: java

```
String text = "Vova", myText = "Vova";
text.equals(myText) ? System.out.print("Переменные схожи") : System.out.print("Переменные различаются");
```

На выводе получаю ошибку:

> `Error:(6, 31) java: not a statement`

Answer (score 1):

```
String text = "Vova", myText = "Vova";
System.out.print(text.equals(myText) ? "Переменные схожи" : "Переменные различаются");
```

> Тернарный оператор `?:` в Java единственный оператор, который принимает три операнды.
>
> `логическоеВыржанеие ? выражение1: выражение2`
>
> Первый операнд должен быть логическим выражением. Второй и третий операнды - любым выражением, которое возвращает любое значение.

`System.out.print()` ничего не возвращает, поэтому и была ошибка.

> Операнд - элемент данных, над которым производятся машинные операции.